# Socket emits not sending from client (sending fine from server)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

The following is a unit test to show the behavior that I'm experiencing, which I recognize as different than what I've experienced before. In essence, the way I was using sockets before (maybe two months ago) stopped working sometime between then and now. I'm not sure what happened. My previously working code has broken.

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html' });
    var html = "<html><head><script src=\"/socket.io/socket.io.js\"></script>\
                        <script>var sock = io.connect();\
                        sock.on('sup', function(data) {\
                            console.log(\"whoo\");\
                            sock.emit('howdy', {'hi' : 'ho'});\
                        });</script></head></html>";
    res.end(html);
}).listen(8080);

socketio.listen(server, {log:false}).on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('howdy', function(data){console.log("HI!");});
    socket.emit("sup", {"hey" :"yo"});
});
```

What I would expect from the code is the following sequence of events:

1. socket connects, server emits "sup" message.
2. client receives "sup" message and logs "whoo"
3. client sends "howdy" message
4. server receives "howdy" message and logs "HI!"

Step 4 is not occurring at all. (and therefore I assume step 3 might not be happening, either)

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated socket.io, and it's working now.

Comment: facepalm, great job anyway, it happened to all of us :p

Comment: @Jujuleder yeah, I didn't realize that the client-side version is just a link to the most recent version that socket.io hosts. I thought "Well, I'm on an out-of-date version, but the out-of-date version used to work..."

Answer (score 1):

Your client side code is essentially this

```
var sock = io.connect(); 
console.log("Gets here");
sock.on('sup', function(data) { 
     console.log("whoo"); 
});
sock.emit('howdy', {'hi' : 'ho'});
```

I'm assuming it will work if you just move the emit into the handler.

```
var sock = io.connect(); 
console.log("Gets here");
sock.on('sup', function(data) { 
     console.log("whoo"); 
     sock.emit('howdy', {'hi' : 'ho'});
});
```

Or you can try listening for the connect event

```
var sock = io.connect(); 
console.log("Gets here");
sock.on('sup', function(data) { 
     console.log("whoo"); 
});
sock.on('connect', function() {
     sock.emit('howdy', {'hi' : 'ho'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't solve my problem. Check out my revised code (I pared it down even further)